# Electron app use specific network interface on windows?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an app that I need to run two instances of, each using a different USB network interface with a different IP (but on the same subnet). My app connects to my server via websockets.

By default windows will pick the most optimal interface, but I need to ensure the apps start on different IP's but since the subnet's are the same it picks the same one for both.

I successfully got it to work with ForceBindIP, but I'm wondering if there's a way to configure this directly in my app instead of relying on a 3rd party tool.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ForceBindIP\ForceBindIP64.exe" 192.168.2.11 "C:\Users\x\projects\myapp\node_modules\electron\dist\electron.exe" "C:\Users\x\projects\myapp"\
```

It looks like the `request()` library does allow for a interface IP to be specified. Issue is, I'm using websocket in the renderer which doesn't seem to have any option for the interface to use. I'd like to make it configurable from my app where it shows the available interfaces and you can choose which one from a dropdown. Is this possible?

[image]